# How to resize bootstrap modal according to iframe size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Actually i have an iframe page where i load some data from database in a table so the height of the iframe would be different.

Like now the modal is loading fine the iframe and if it height is bigger than 300px there will be a scroll bar but the issue is when the content is smaller than 300px like you can see on the screen there is a lot of white space.

[image]

So i would be able to remove that whitespace and size the modal according to iframe height by setting a max height where should compare the scrollbars.

Here is the modal code:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-light">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">User update: </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                 <div id="body" class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

                    <div class="embed-responsive z-depth-1-half" style="height: 100%; max-height:300px;">
                        <iframe id="frame" class="embed-responsive-item" src="user.aspx"></iframe>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure about this, but I think that you will need to use postMessage (or BroadcastChannel) from inside iframe to send message with height of the table and set height attribute or inline style on iframe, because iframe height and height of the page inside is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove height:100% and add

```
#body {
    max-height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: without the height:100% in embed class the iframe content is not even shown

Comment: How about height: 100vh